# Customizar mensagens de erro na conexão com banco de dados

Tags: php, conexão

Bom aqui no stack eu encontrei alguns tópicos que me ajudaram, sou novo com PHP, e queria fazer minha conexão retornar uma mensagem customizada sem fazer com que mostre aqueles *warnings*.

Só que quando adiciono a verificação nada acontece, meu código completo abaixo.

```
<?php
class Connect {

    private $Connect;

    public function Connect() {
        $this->Connection();

        if(connection_aborted() == TRUE) {
            $this->Connection();
        }
    }

    public function Connection() {
        global $Config;

        $this->Connect = new mysqli($Config['mysql']['hostname'], $Config['mysql']['username'], $Config['mysql']['password'], $Config['mysql']['database'], $Config['mysql']['dataport']);

        if($this->Connect == false){
            exit('Falha na conexão, verifique Config.php');
        }

        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode personalizar a mensagem de erro, transformando os erros retornados por execptions com [mysqli_report](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) para evitar [warnings relacionados a índices](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60213/91) prefira: `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` no lugar de: `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL`.

Adicione um try no bloco onde deseja lançar a exception e use o catch para exibir a mensagem personalizada, lembre de implementar um rotina log com o erro do banco para facilitar a detecção de erros.

```
public function __construct() {
    //linha que torna os erros em exceptions
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $this->Connection();

    if(connection_aborted() == TRUE) {
        $this->Connection();
    }
}

public function Connection() {

    global $Config;
    try {
        $this->Connect = new mysqli($Config['mysql']['hostname'],
                $Config['mysql']['username'], $Config['mysql']['password'],
                $Config['mysql']['database'], $Config['mysql']['dataport']);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        exit('Falha na conexão, verifique Config.php');
    }
```

Prefira definir o construtor como um construtor e não depender da sorte, apartir do php 5.3.3 o mecanismo mudou. Um método com o mesmo nome da **classe dentro de um namespace** não é tratado como construtor.

[Construtores - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Prefira:

```
function __construct() {
```

No lugar de:

```
public function Connect() {
```

Comment: Obrigado você respondeu corretamente a minha pergunta... funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 5):

Recomendo a utilizar PDO, já que está começando isso facilitará sua vida e em muito. Ele suporta mais de 10 tipos de banco de dados. Um exemplo de conexão com suporte a verificação está abaixo:

```
<?php
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
            print_r($row);
        }
       $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
       print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
       die();
    }
?>
```

Comment: As vezes é preciso deixar claro para o PDO lançar exceptions com o [setAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) ou direto no construtor.

Comment: Estou estudando mysqli primeiro, eu tentei PDO mas achei muito mais difícil, sim a hora que eu terminar meu mini projeto vou estudar PDO orientado a objetos!