# No índice utilizado na consulta / declaração preparada

Tags: php, mysqli, índices

Estou com um warning estranho no meu código, quando tem apenas um dado na DB ele reconhece e funciona direitinho, mas quando eu insiro mais de 1 dado na DB ele me mostra o seguinte warning:

> No index used in query/prepared statement SELECT * FROM con_users "SELECT * FROM con_users"

Para fazer a consulta no phpmyadmin usei o seguinte código:

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/settings.php';
require_once 'includes/autoloader.php';

$querys = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM con_users");

while($ln = $db->FetchArray($querys)) {

    $id = $ln['id'];
    $nome = $ln['nome'];
    $lastname = $ln['lastname'];

}

echo 'id: '.$id.'<br/>';
echo 'nome: '.$nome.'<br/>';
echo 'sobrenome: '.$lastname.'<br/>';?>
```

Bom quem puder me ajudar, agradeço...

Comment: Mostra como tens a tabela `con_users` na base de dados

Comment: está assim, id int 11 not null primary key auto incremento, nome varchar 255 , lastname varchar 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580039/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-mysqli-sql-exception-with-message-no-index-us#comment32595828_9842097) você deveria trocar o nivel de rigor de [mysqli_report](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php) de: `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL` para: `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`, dessa forma a extensão não reportará warnings sobre índices em geral.

Comment: Acho que ele quer resolver o *warnig* e não que ele deixe de aparecer...

Comment: Isso eu queria resolver, mas se você me disser que não problema alguma mudar pra MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT posso tentar?

Comment: O banco disse executei uma consulta em tablescan, que é uma varedura pela tabela inteira é a operação mais lenta. Você pode definir um índice para a PK e ver se o warning some. A menos que esteja fazendo um tunning, não problema em omitir os warnings de índices.

Comment: Eu mudei mesmo para : MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT e já está resolvido, mas antes de marcar sua resposta como resolvido, poderia me responder se se com isso os erros dos try e catch serão mostrados normalmente ?

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves, sim ele irá lançar exception para os demais erros.