# Como criar Exceptions para tratar statement com Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, exceção

Estou migrando do PDO para o Mysqli e quando fazia alguma operação com o banco, o bloco de verificação era assim:

```
$query = $db->prepare("ppapapa sql sql");

try {
        $query -> execute();
        return $query -> fetchAll();

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e -> getMessage());
    }
```

Como seria esse tratamento de erros com Mysqli?

Comment: Mas por que você está migrando? PDO é nativo e mais recomedado, pois se precisar mudar de SGBD não é preciso mudar o código, apenas a classe de conexão.

Comment: Eu li que ele perde em desempenho para o MySqli e como eu só vou usar SQL, entende...

Comment: @MarceloGomes quem disse que é o mais recomendado? Na prática, fora alguns softwares genéricos feito pra todo mundo usar, ninguém precisa trocar banco de dados. As pessoas inventam esse "requisito".

Comment: Acredito que valha a pena rever, se não me engano a perda de desempenho entre PDO e MySQLi fica entre 2% - 4%, é apenas uma sugestão caso a preocupação seja somente desempenho.

Comment: Entendo essa coisa da portabilidade, mas não vejo vantagem, pois não trocarei o tipo do banco...

Comment: @bigown eu também pensava assim até que um cliente pediu que a aplicação usasse  postgres...... a regra sempre é desacoplar..... ou estou enganado?

Comment: @MarceloGomes não existe regra. Só porque um cliente pede, não quer dizer que deva ser feito. Eu nunca vi um caso onde o banco de dados foi bem escolhido e precisou trocar. Trocar por que deu vontade não é um bom motivo para fazê-lo. E essencialmente todos banco de dados podem fazer qualquer coisa que os demais. Em geral a mudança necessária está longe de ser apenas o objeto de conexão, a não ser que tenha usado o mínimo denominador comum, aí a aplicação ficou bem ruim para atender um requisito improvável. Já vi quem fez isto do jeito certo, mas ficou caro. Não é algo simples como dizem.

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa habilitar as exceções com:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
```

Ou só:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Depois pode usar normalmente:

```
$query = $db->prepare("ppapapa sql sql");
try {
    $query -> execute();
    return $query -> fetchAll();
} catch(mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    die($e -> getMessage());
}
```

Documentação do [`mysqli_report()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php).

Se não quiser fazer isto pode tratar os erros individualmente:

```
if (!mysqli->query($insadquery)) die(mysqli->errno . " - " . $mysqli->error);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Exception/MySQLi.php).

Muitas vezes esta forma é preferível.

[Documentação de toda `mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 4):

A função que transformar os erros em exceptions no MySQLi é use a função [mysqli_report()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php).

Como o MySQLi é uma API especializada, ela possui alguns recursos interessantes, como detectar  erros comuns no método `prepare()`. alguns deles são:

Praticamente todos são erros de digitação ou algum valor mal formatado.

```
1146 # Table 'nome' doesn't exist
1054 # Unknown column 'nome' in 'clause'
1064 # You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Para pegar esses erros use a combinação de `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`e `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR` e deixe o `prepare()` dentro do catch. Demais erros como violação de chave estrangeira ou repetição de ids, são verificados no `execute()`.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT|MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

try {
    $query = $db->prepare("ppapapa sql sql");
    $query -> execute();
    $result = $query->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_all();
}catch(mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    echo 'SQLState: '. $e->getCode() .' # '. $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Quando usar `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL`?**

`MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL` deve usado para debugging e identificação de gargalos, caso um consulta não utilize o indíce, será lançada um exception que desviará o fluxo para o catch mesmo que nenhum *erro de verdade* tenha ocorrido, o que é bem indigesto para um sistema já em produção.

[Exemplo dessa exception](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60213/91).

> No index used in query/prepared statement SELECT * FROM ...

`MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL` ou `MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX` fornecem boas pistas sobre porque algumas consultas estão lentas, utilize quando adequado.